# Function works well on dummy data, on real data "Error: grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels"?

Tags: r, lapply

I have created a function, which works well on dummy data. But, when I run this function on real data, I've got back an error

```
Error in wilcox.test.formula(tab[[dependent]] ~ as.factor(tab$group),  : 
      grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

and warning messages:

```
In wilcox.test.default(x = c(11.2558701380866, 31.8401548036613,  :   cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

So, "thresholding" in my function **seems not correctly split real data in two groups**. Also, the **sub-setting of the real data is not correct**. But I don't understand why?? The dummy and real tables structure seem the same:

---

Structure of dummy and real data:

**Dummy:**

```
> str(tab)
'data.frame':   80 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ infGrad    : num  14.15 12.53 3.03 9.21 16.36 ...
 $ distance   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ uniqueGroup: Factor w/ 2 levels "x","y": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
```

**Real:**

```
> str(tab)
'data.frame':   142 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ distance   : num  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 ...
 $ infGrad    : num  11.3 17.4 31.8 11.1 47.8 ...
 $ uniqueGroup: Factor w/ 6 levels "x",..: 5 2 5 2 5 5 5 5 3 6 ...
```

---

I have found that `NAs` might cause these problems, or specification of formula of the `wilcox.test(y ~ x)`.

So, I tried to add `na.omit` to my function, and instead of `wilcox.test(y~x)` use `wilcox.test(y, x)`. None of these have worked.

Do you have any ideas **how to make my function work** or how to **make it more robust** to accept my real data? Your help is highly appreciated.

---

What the code does:

1. classify data in two groups by "moving threshold"
2. test statistical differences between those groups.

I run the function with nested `lapply` to vary my thresholds and different data subsets.

My dummy data:

```
set.seed(10)

infGrad <- c(rnorm(20, mean=14, sd=8),
            rnorm(20, mean=13, sd=5),
            rnorm(20, mean=8, sd=2),
            rnorm(20, mean=7, sd=1))
distance <- rep(c(1:4), each = 20)
uniqueGroup <- rep(c("x", "y"), 40)

tab<-data.frame(infGrad, distance, uniqueGroup)


# Create moving threshols function
movThreshold <- function(th, tab, dependent, ...) {
  tab<-na.omit(tab)

  # Classify data 
  tab$group<- ifelse(tab$distance < th, "a", "b") # does not WORK on REAL data

  # Calculate wincoxon test 
  test<-wilcox.test(tab[[dependent]] ~ as.factor(tab$group),  # specify column name
                    data = tab)

  # Put results in a vector 
  c(th, dependent, round(test$p.value, 3))

}

# Define two vectors to run through
# unique group
gr.list<-unique(tab$uniqueGroup)

# unique threshold
th.list<-c(2,3,4)


# apply function over threshols and subset
res<-lapply(gr.list, function(x) lapply(th.list,
                                        movThreshold,
                                        tab = tab[uniqueGroup == x,], # does not work on REAL data
                                        dependent = "infGrad"))
```

What seems not working on real data:

1. Groups classification within the function

   ```
    tab$group<- ifelse(tab$distance < th, "a", "b")
   ```
2. Data subsetting in nested `lapply` loop

   ```
    subsetting: tab = tab[uniqueGroup == x,]
   ```

Comment: Your example does not reproduce your error, which makes it difficult to help.

Comment: yes, I know... because my reproductible example work, but I can not fit it on my data... which however seems to have good structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue probably happens because of a single value group.
You can reproduce the error for instance adding a high value to `th.list`.

```
# unique threshold
th.list<-c(2,3,4,100)
```

The easiest way to avoid this is checking for the length of `tab$group` before performing the test.
This change in the function should suffice:

```
movThreshold <- function(th, tab, dependent, ...) {
  tab<-na.omit(tab)

  # Classify data 
  tab$group<- ifelse(tab$distance < th, "a", "b") # does not WORK on REAL data

  # Check there are two groups
  if(length(unique(tab$group))<2){return(NA)}
  # Calculate wincoxon test 
  test<-wilcox.test(tab[[dependent]] ~ as.factor(tab$group),  # specify column name
                    data = tab)

  # Put results in a vector 
  c(th, dependent, round(test$p.value, 3))

}
```